# How to responsive, vertically align image with CSS

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to responsively & vertically center an image on a page. I found several solutions online, but none are working for me. The image is stuck in the upper left hand corner. Any leads would be awesome. I'm banging my head :)

[Here is the test page](http://mccanney.net/mbhb/index.html)

[here is an image of the desired finished page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1pma.jpg)

```css
    html {

      font-family: sans-serif;

      /* 1 */

      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;

      /* 2 */

      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;

      /* 2 */

      background: url("http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/bg-giraffe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;

      -webkit-background-size: cover;

      -moz-background-size: cover;

      -o-background-size: cover;

      background-size: cover;

    }

    img.product1:empty {

      top: 50%;

      left: 50%;

      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/product-lg-hippo.jpg" class="product1" />
</div>
```

Comment: As a general note, to get `top: 50%; left: 50%;` working, you need `position: absolute` or `position: relative` on the element. You don't want to combine that with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: in your "desired page" you have white (as in the image isn't stretched) underneath the image. is that what you want?

Comment: @sec actually that's how you align absolute positioned elements, w/ the `transform: translate` function. but you are correct, she does need `absolute` or `relative` for that to work

Comment: You can't use `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover`, the former will forbid the latter from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `position:absolute` to the image within the div. See below :

```css
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    /* 1 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    /* 2 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    /* 2 */
    background: url("../images/bg-giraffe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
img.product1:empty {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute; /*You would need to add this*/
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" class="product1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

display:table works fine from IE8 ...

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  background: url("http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/bg-giraffe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
img.product1:empty {
  /* not too sure what's your idea here , a background defaut, a div sized, generated content inserted  ? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/product-lg-hippo.jpg" class="product1" />
</div>
```

easy way with young brother : display:flex;

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  background: url("http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/bg-giraffe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img.product1:empty {
  /* not too sure what's your idea here , a background defaut, a div sized, generated content inserted  ? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/product-lg-hippo.jpg" class="product1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! You can set horizontal and vertical position with `top` and `left` in your `product1` class as you have done.  And then this is either absolutely positioned to the viewport or relatively positioned to the parent div.

See it in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chuddayo/pen/YyYzpE).

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/product-lg-hippo.jpg" class="product1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background: url("http://mccanney.net/mbhb/images/bg-giraffe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

img.product1:empty {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```